# django basic user validation in views.py

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-validation

I am using this code to validate logged in / authenticated users in my `views.py`.

```
@login_required
def my_view(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'User not Found')
    if user == request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
        variables = RequestContext(request, {})
        return render_to_response('my_template.html', variables)
```

is there another way (ie less code) to validate users, or do I need to put that in every view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user` with `login_required` ***is*** the current logged-in user, you don't need to check it again by username, and thus there is no need to check `is_authenticated`. If you just want to render a page which have different logic for different user type, try the code below, if not, just use `request.user`. Also, use `get_object_or_404` and `render` shortcuts.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
@login_required
def my_view(request, username):
    if username == request.user.username:
        return render(request, 'my_template.html', {})
    # render the page of user who is not request.user
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    # ...
```

Comment: thank you very much, why `render` is better than `render_to_response` and why prefer `get_object_or_404` instead of `try/except`?

Comment: @xpanta just as their module name `shortcuts` stands for, they help you to type less boil-plate code and thus less possibility of making error. Also, `get_object_or_404` are almost same w/ try/except which trys to get an model object and raises Http404 if failed; [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is same with render_to_redering but always use RequestContext